# Redirect any request to index.php using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I need to redirect any url's to index.php, where I'll process it.
Now .htaccess contains it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

And it almost works, but paths like "/.htaccess" returns 403. But as I understand it won't rewrite if there's existing file or directory in the path, e.g. "/robots.txt" will return real "robots.txt" file and the request won't be redirected to index.php.

But if I remove RewriteCond lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

then site breaks: any resource (css, js, img...) will contain index.php content instead of it's own content, and paths like "/.htaccess" still return 403 instead of redirection to index.php.

How can I just redirect ANY path to index.php, with no checking file/directory/extension/etc?

Comment: _“any resource (css, js, img...) will contain index.php content instead of it's own content”_ - and how exactly is that surprising now? You did deliberately rewrite the requests for those to your index.php, so your index.php would be responsible for serving the right content for those now.

Comment: _“and paths like "/.htaccess" still return 403 instead of redirection to index.php”_ - requests for those files usually get blocked by the server configuration, these requests will it not even make it as far as that your rewriting from the .htaccess could apply.

Comment: I couldn't think that it redirects resource-request when I build the page. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the parameter:
Redirect permanent /var/www/yoursite/index.php